# php code to while loop a table reutrns only empty rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
 <?php

$batchcourseid = $_POST['batchcourseid'];
$coursestatus = $_POST['coursestatus'];
$batchname = $_POST['batchname'];



$conn=mysql_connect("localhost","root","qwerty");
mysql_select_db("MIS");
$sql=("SELECT * from batch where CourseID = '$batchcourseid' AND BatchName LIKE '%$batchname%'");

$results = mysql_query($sql, $conn);

?>
<table width="1070" height="54" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td height="23">BatchID</td>
    <td>CourseID</td>
    <td>Batch Name</td>
    <td>Number Of Students</td>
    <td>Start Date</td>
    <td>End Date</td>
    </tr>
  <?php  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) ?>
  <?php { ?>
  <tr>
    <td height="23"><?php echo $row['BatchID'] ?>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><?php echo $row['CourseID']; ?>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><?php echo $row['BatchName']; ?>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><?php echo $row['NumStud']; ?>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><?php echo $row['StartDate']; ?>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><?php echo $row['EndDate']; ?>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
```

this code is supposed  to give  a  row in a  table.but its just  the  empty row that appears.what have i done wrong?
all the  columns and  text exist too

Comment: What kind of error do you get?

Comment: In a productive environment you should be aware of SQL injections! Check some documentation about bind variables, e.g. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php :)

Comment: i don't know if this changes anything or not...
your $sql which has the query... it has () in the starting an end... can you see if you still have error if the $sql is just string except the ()...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%` has to be part of `LIKE` string, so it should be between `'`, not before/after it:

```
BatchName LIKE '%$batchname%'"
```

Comment: Beaten up by seconds. Got busy in editing the question ;)

Comment: i ran into a problem with the next section of the code.and updates the q,can you try to help me on it?

Comment: No, because it's no longer SQL problem. You should ask another question for that one.

Answer (score 2):

like should be written as follows:

```
LIKE '%$batchname%'
```

% should be within the quotes.

Answer (score 2):

In your select query please check like operator %

```
$sql=("SELECT * from batch where CourseID = ".$batchcourseid." AND BatchName LIKE '%".$batchname."%' ");
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the `%` inside the text (`'%".$batchname."%'`):

```
$sql="SELECT * from batch where CourseID = '".$batchcourseid"' ".
         "AND BatchName LIKE '%".$batchname."%'";
```

Depending on your environment you should be aware of [SQL injections](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysql-php-sql-injection.php). So you might rather use [bind variables](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php):

```
$sql="SELECT * from batch where CourseID = ? AND BatchName LIKE ?";
```

Set first parameter to `$batchname`  and the second to `"%".$batchname."%"`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this with % inside the text:-

```
$sql=("SELECT * from batch where CourseID = '$batchcourseid' 
AND BatchName LIKE '%$batchname%'");
```

instead of

```
$sql=("SELECT * from batch where CourseID = '$batchcourseid' 
AND BatchName LIKE %'$batchname'%");
```

**EDIT AFTER UPDATION IN QUESTION:-**

```
 $sql=("SELECT * from batch where CourseID = ".$batchcourseid." AND BatchName LIKE '%".$batchname."%'
```

Comment: can you help me fix the  updates error

Comment: Sure...Try this now:- $sql=("SELECT * from batch where CourseID = ".$batchcourseid." AND BatchName LIKE '%".$batchname."%'

Comment: Just for your consideration. If you are not satisfied with the answer. Do not accept it as most of the people will not put time to it as they might think that this has already been answered.

Comment: Did that worked for you???

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql=("SELECT * from batch where CourseID = '$batchcourseid' AND BatchName LIKE %'$batchname'%");
```

change it to

```
$sql="SELECT * from batch where CourseID = '$batchcourseid' AND BatchName LIKE '%$batchname%'";
```